# Matlab replace axis labels

Tags: matlab, axis-labels

Plot with x axis representing days from Monday to Sunday. So far I have the labels in plot from in numbers from 1 to 7. How to replace them to strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel'{'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'});
```